# -Dmaven.compiler.executable=...jdk5/bin/javac ignored on jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am running Jenkins ver. 1.532. I have created a maven job and tried to configure it to run java 5 using the jenkins JDK auto installer configured to download/install jdk5 from oracle. But when I run the build I get:

```
ERROR: [JENKINS-18403] JDK 5 not supported to run Maven; retrying with slave Java and setting compile/test properties to point to /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk5
maven31-agent.jar already up to date
maven31-interceptor.jar already up to date
maven3-interceptor-commons.jar already up to date
[my-project] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -cp /var/jenkins/maven31-agent.jar:/var/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.2.jar:/var/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main
```

It seems that it falls back to building with jdk7 (the default). I have then tried to add the following to the Builds/Goals and options section:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.compiler.executable=/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk5/bin/javac
```

But it does not have any effect. Should it not be possible to force a JDK version using `-Dmaven.compiler.executable` option?

**EDIT:**
I have now switched to the jenkins freestyle project type and use the maven-enforcer-plugin to fail the build if a jdk != 1.5 is used when building the project. See last paragraph here:

https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/how_to_cross_compile_for

and Note here:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: Try using maven 2.2.1

Comment: can you explain why you cannot use jdk7 but with source+output set to java 5? wouldn't that be the easiest option?

Comment: Do you mean http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html ?. From the note I understand that you can still run into runtime errors with this approach. So it seems that the only way to be 100% sure is by building with a jdk version no higher than what you want to be compatible with.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#executable , `-Dmaven.compiler.executable` will override compiler executable only for Maven compiler plugin, and not for the whole Jenkins job. If you need only to compile your sources using JAVA5 - setting this property should be enough to enforce Maven compiler to use JAVA5. Even in case when Jenkins job will use JDK 1.6 or higher for running the Maven launcher.

And, of course, you need to set JDK 1.6 or higher in Jenkins job settings. Since Jenkins cannot run Maven using JAVA5, you should not use it.

Comment: I have now changed to a freeStyle project using Dmaven.compiler.executable option + the maven-enforcer-plugin to fail the build if the project is being build with a jdk version > 1.5

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar case which my help you.

My maven is running with JDK 1.7 but I wanna build a project with JDK 8.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

if I would just run
`mvn clean install`
I would get an error like:

> Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8

When I set the `JAVA_HOME` to the JDK 8 it would work like a charm, but I don't want to do that.

The maven compiler has the option, like you mentioned `executeable` however this does not work in my case, it would still fail with the same error message.

I came up with the following command

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.compiler.executable=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac -Dmaven.compiler.fork=true
```

As additional information I appended the output of `mvn -v`

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.x
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.11.0-20-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```